# Why is $|(x-2)| < \delta \le 1$ true when proving $\lim_{x\to2}(3x^2-x)=10$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I found this exercise (and the solution) on the web. Shamelessly following the solution step by step, there is one small thing that isn't very clear to me (highlighted in red below).

This is solution **6** of [this website](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preclimsoldirectory/PrecLimSol.html#SOLUTION%206).

---

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to2}(3x^2-x)=10$$

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$

We want to prove that

$$|x-2| < \delta \iff |3x^2-x-10| < \epsilon$$

For some $\delta$ we will determine soon.

So, we got

$$|3x^2-x-10| < \epsilon$$

$$|(x-2)| \cdot |(3x+5)| < \epsilon$$

Assume that

$$0 < \delta \le 1$$

Which is fine, because any such value lower than $\delta$ would still work anyway.

Let

$$\color{red}{|(x-2)| < \delta \le 1}$$

**(Here's what I don't get: isn't it possible for $|(x-2)|$ to be actually greater than $1$? Who is to say that it really is lesser than $1$ or $\delta$?)**

Which implies that

$$x-2 < 1$$

$$3x-6<3$$

$$3x<9$$

$$3x+5 < 14$$

Therefore, we got that

$$|(x-2)| \cdot |(3x+5)| < 14\delta$$

$$14\delta = \epsilon$$

$$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{14}$$

The answer is:

$$\delta = \min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{14}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

$|(x-2)|$ is going to be greater than 1 somewhere, but as $x$ gets closer to 2 (the limits which is to be proved), $|(x-2)|$ correspondingly becomes arbitrarily close to 0, to the point where it can be said to be less than $\delta$.

The proof is then establishing that whenever $|(x-2)| < \delta \leq 1$, it naturally follows that $|3x^2−x−10|<\epsilon$.